# Additional file in Adobe JavaScript to automatically generated email

Tags: javascript, adobe

I'm trying to attach the original and an additional file to an automatically generated email.
I am fairly new with Adobe and JavaScript so any help is appreciated.

My ideas so far are as follows:

```
this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: cToAddr, cSubject: cSubLine, cMsg: cBody, cAttach: ["\\\\test\\test\\TEST\\test.pdf"]});
```

I replaced the Actual path with test in this case.
I expected this to give me the predefined email with text (which it does) but I don't get the 2nd file I try to attach in this email.